# How to get sent emails using pop3 node js package

Tags: node.js, email, pop3

I tried to get inbox using pop3 npm package. I am success on getting incoming emails using this line of codes,

```
client = new POP3Client(credit.pop_port, credit.pop_host, {
                tlserrs: true,
                enabletls: true,
                debug: false
            });
            client.on("error", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err) {

                client.quit();
            }));
            client.on("invalid-state", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (cmd) {
            }));
            client.on("locked", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (cmd) {

            }));
            client.on("connect", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
                client.login(credit.user, credit.password);
            }));
            client.on("login", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (status) {
                if (status) {
                    client.stat();
                } else {
                    client.login(credit.user, credit.password);
                }
            }));
            client.on("stat", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (status, data) {
                if (data[1] !== "0")
                    client.uidl();
            }));
```

But the problem is I only getting incoming emails. I would like to know what emails I sent to other email address too.

Is it possible by using this package? 
Is it possible to POP3?

Comment: POP3 typically doesn't store sent messages, because they are sent through a completely separate protocol (SMTP). When using POP3 with a standard email client, the client will usually save a copy of sent messages locally in a "Sent" folder, the message is never transferred over POP3.

Comment: So there is no Sent items in all mailbox of pop3?

Comment: Correct. One option might be for you to BCC yourself when sending the emails, then a copy will be delivered to your code through POP3. You would need to do some kind of manual check to distinguish normal received emails from these sent emails (e.g. match the from address against your own address).